# Create parameters for sub-process jbpm

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

I have the following figure:

[image]

Escalate to next level is a sub-process which needs a lot of variables, however the parent process doesn't need them and in fact the `PerapareParameters` task should generate them and pass it to the process. How can I do that in a way that doesn't require me to map them in the data items for the process. I'm using the eclipse plugin. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

To pass variables in sub-process you have to perform variable mapping. I cant see any other way to pass variables.